# facing ImportError: No module named discriminant_analysis

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, classification

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04 , python=2.7 , numpy=1.10.1 , scikit-learn=0.17.1 , scipy=0.17.1` but I have Import Error both in `IDLE` and in `Spyder` (conda=4.1.3 , conda-env=2.5.0a0) in the import part of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import csv
import pandas
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
import re
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn import neighbors
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier, AdaBoostClassifier
```

I am facing the error as:

> ImportError: No module named discriminant_analysis

However in terminal(Python) I have tried to import: **LinearDiscriminantAnalysis** as follow:

```
 from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
```

there was not any error?! I don't know what is the reason and how can I fix it?

Comment: I would guess that you have installed things both with conda and with pip and they look at different installation paths. Can you verify that?

Comment: yes I checked and it has been installed with both pip and conda I can see that they are installed in 2 different locations but do you mean if I should change any setting or if I should uninstall one?

Comment: No. But you maybe have different versions installed and the LinearDiscriminantAnalysis class wsa renamed or added later.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. It turned out that there were two different installations of `scikit`:

- one in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/` (which **does not have** the `discriminant_analysis` module); and
- the other in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/` (which
  has the module);

The shell and the IDE were pointing to different ones.

So you'll need to harmonize them. In my case, 'harmonising' meant uninstalling the problematic one (i.e. the one that didn't contain the module) using

`sudo apt-get --purge remove python-sklearn`